# Form Submits After Alert Box "OK" Is Clicked

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, alert

I have a form with a checkbox that prompts the user to agree but somehow the form gets submitted anyway right after the user clicks okay in the alert box. Is there any way I can stop this from happening?
The form is at...

http://www.dreamhomevacationrentals.com/hotels/spanish-modern-retreat/

Click "Availability" from the left side menu and then click the blue "Book Now" button to see the form in action.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've already updated your `check_agree` function to use `e.preventDefault();` instead of `return false;`, but it's not working. Try changing it to use `event.preventDefault();` instead.

Comment: It worked! Hey dude, you don't know how much of a headache stuff like this can be for someone who isn't a javascript guru like you. Thank you so much!!!  And thanx for following up.

Comment: Hey bro, I was wondering if you could look as the last question that I posted today, relating to a paypal form submit, and maybe give me some input on that since no one else seems to be able to help? @Troy Gizzi

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your code available, but with 99% certainty you need to add a `e.preventDefault()` in your submit handler.

Comment: or just set chackbox as required with your validation.

Comment: @GüvenAltuntaş Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your point?

Comment: validation already using e.preventDefault to stop form brother. So he should add this box in valdiaiton and run alert there. and thats not my negative point. your answer is right im fixing that vote.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Vulcronos "This does not provide an answer to the question." Actually it does; if you'll notice, I suggested the `preventDefault()` solution, which was correct (and an hour ahead of the accepted answer). "To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post." I did that as well. Perhaps I didn't need to restate it down here, but if you need to criticize something, the lack of code in the question itself is probably an easier target.

Comment: </passive-aggressive-response> :)